# Rails way to render different actions & views based on user type?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a couple different user types (buyers, sellers, admins).

I'd like them all to have the same account_path URL, but to use a different action and view.

I'm trying something like this...

```
class AccountsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :render_by_user, :only => [:show]

  def show
   # see *_show below
  end

  def admin_show
    ...
  end

  def buyer_show
    ...
  end

  def client_show
    ...
  end
end
```

This is how I defined render_by_user in ApplicationController...

```
  def render_by_user
    action = "#{current_user.class.to_s.downcase}_#{action_name}"
    if self.respond_to?(action) 
      instance_variable_set("@#{current_user.class.to_s.downcase}", current_user) # e.g. set @model to current_user
      self.send(action)
    else
      flash[:error] ||= "You're not authorized to do that."
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end
```

It calls the correct *_show method in the controller.  But still tries to render "show.html.erb" and doesn't look for the correct template I have in there named "admin_show.html.erb" "buyer_show.html.erb" etc.

I know I can just manually call `render "admin_show"` in each action but I thought there might be a cleaner way to do this all in the before filter.

Or has anyone else seen a plugin or more elegant way to break up actions & views by user type?  Thanks!

Btw, I'm using Rails 3 (in case it makes a difference).

Comment: Other than loading a unique view, is there much difference in the logic of each action?

Comment: Yep each controller will be substantially different.  Probably should have mentioned that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on how different the view templates are, it might be beneficial to move some of this logic into the `show` template instead and do the switching there:

```
<% if current_user.is_a? Admin %>
<h1> Show Admin Stuff! </h1>
<% end %>
```

But to answer your question, you need to specify which template to render. This should work if you set up your controller's `@action_name`. You could do this in your `render_by_user` method instead of using a local `action` variable:

```
def render_by_user
  self.action_name = "#{current_user.class.to_s.downcase}_#{self.action_name}"
  if self.respond_to?(self.action_name) 
    instance_variable_set("@#{current_user.class.to_s.downcase}", current_user) # e.g. set @model to current_user
    self.send(self.action_name)
  else
    flash[:error] ||= "You're not authorized to do that."
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

Comment: Yep - it makes sense, but was hoping there was a way to do this entirely in the `render_by_user` before filter. Thanks for the post!

Comment: oh cool!  Didn't know you could set the action_name like that.  Yep, this looks like a winner.  Will try it out!