# Rails polymorphic views and actions based on STI type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This seems to be a similar question, but the answer may be different two years down the line: [Rails way to render different actions & views based on user type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542928/rails-way-to-render-different-actions-views-based-on-user-type)

I have an STI model that can have many types. Often, but not always, the views will be different depending on the type. Equally the controller actions may differ in logic depending on the type. I want to avoid the high maintenance cost of having to change if/elsif conditionals based on the type.

I can think of several ways that I could write some helper functions/modules to make this easier, but wonder if any gems built for this purpose already exist.

Your thoughts appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a separate controller for different STI types as long as you declare them in your routes file. ie.

```
Base < ActiveRecord::Base
end

Foo < Base
end

Bar < Base
end


#config/routes.rb
resources :foos
resources :bars
```

Then you just need to generate a controller for `foo` and a controller for `bar` and their respective methods/views.

For common elements you can use partials for views, and the Base model. (You might be able to use the Base controller as well somehow. I'm not sure about that though)